# Download RSS files in WebView

Tags: android, rss

I am developing an Android application and I want download some files from a server.

My problem is that I can not download the RSS file. I have implemented a WebView and 'onDownloadStart' method to download all files from a server which is accessed from the application, but the '.png' '.txt' and '.rss' files are not downloaded, their contents are displayed in WebView.

How I can do to download them?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at this, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html Why do you want to download the in a webview?

Comment: I have a WebView to access to some URLs from a server and give user the option to display or download each content server, so although I get the RSS file to show in the WebView, the 'onDownloadStart' method does not run as if it happens with other formats for downloading content in the app